# Почему прекращается запись на флешку arduino-uno после примерно 140 раза?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

хочу написать логгер, собирающий данные с датчика давления(GY-68) и еще пару показателей. Использую плату-переходник для карты памяти, общается по SPI. Флешка на 2 Gb, arduino uno. Записываю на microsd данные с помощью встроенной библиотеки ардуино SD.Скопировал скетч с примера, c сайта(https://arduinomaster.ru/datchiki-arduino/podklyuchenie-sd-karty-k-arduino/). Примерно до 140 раза записывает все нормально(иногда больше, до 193, рекорд 250 значений примерно), но потом просто вылетает ошибка открытия файла и запись прекращается. Не понимаю почему дальше не идет запись. Такое ощущение, что утечка памяти или вроде того, не знаю в общем.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int PIN_CHIP_SELECT = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
 // Этот пин обязательно должен быть определен как OUTPUT
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

  // Пытаемся проинициализировать модуль
  if (!SD.begin(PIN_CHIP_SELECT)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // Если что-то пошло не так, завершаем работу:
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
}

void loop() {
    // Строка с данными, которые мы поместим в файл:
    String logStringData = "";

    // Считываем данные с портов и записываем в строку
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int sensor = analogRead(i);
        logStringData += String(sensor);
        if (i < 4) {
            logStringData += ",";
        }
    }

    // Открываем файл, но помним, что одновременно можно работать только с одним файлом.
    // Если файла с таким именем не будет, ардуино создаст его.
    File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.csv", FILE_WRITE);

    // Если все хорошо, то записываем строку:
    if (dataFile) {
        dataFile.println(logStringData);
        dataFile.close();
        // Публикуем в мониторе порта для отладки
        Serial.println(logStringData);
    }
    else {
    // Сообщаем об ошибке, если все плохо
        Serial.println("error opening datalog.csv");
    }
 }
```

Менял флешку, форматировал в FAT, FAT 32, гуглил.По сути, ничего дельного не нашел.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конце функции delay(1000), чтобы снимать показания раз в секунду.

Comment: Добавил задержку, к сожалению ничего не поменялось.  Может конечно сам блок не исправен, надо попробовать поменять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело было в плохой SD-карте. Изначально прочитал, что поддержка только карт до 2 Гб, купил на озоне три таких карты с классом скорости 4. Ни одна нормально не заработала нормально. Ни на что особо не надеясь сходил в магазин, купил флешку на 16 Гб с классом 10. Вставил, запустил, заработало. Не знаю в том ли дело, что карта плохая или именно в классе, но так или иначе все заработало.